# Show a chart with very high and very low values

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a bar chart that shows sales against targets for categories as percentages of the targets.

The problem I have is that sometimes one or two of the categories will overperform making the chart hard to read.

Capping the Y axis at 200% has been deemed unacceptable as the usres want to see the top of the bar.

The users have asked if it is possible to crop a section out of the middle, so you would see 0% - 150%, then a gap then (top of high bar - 10%)% to (top of high bar + 10%)%.  I dont think this can be done using the built in chart control.

[image: Here is a sample of how the chart looks]

Does anyone have any ideas of a good way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out scale breaks:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934379(v=sql.100).aspx

No guarantee it will work as hoped with your data, but a good place to start.

Comment: This looks like the exact right solution, unfortunaly they dont do anything.  Probably due to the data/chart type which is a shame.

Comment: what about adding another small chart above the main which will present the top scale the users wishing to see? I think you can play with the GUI to get pretty clean result.

Comment: From the docs "You cannot specify where to place a scale break on your chart. The chart uses its own calculations based on the values in your dataset to determine whether there is sufficient separation between data ranges to draw a scale break." So it sounds like you might be out of luck, sadly. It's counter-intuitive but if you increase report size it might kick in. Alternatively, move the title out of the chart area and again this might be just enough. Other than that the suggestion of @GilPeretz is worth considering.